# Xtext Maven build as POM- and MANIFEST-first

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xtext

Since Xtext 2.9 it is possible to generate Xtext Projects already ready for maven.
Sadly, if I want to build an Eclipse Plugin with my Xtext Language, it generate all POMs as tycho builds. If I uncheck the eclipse-plugin during project generation, it will generate plain maven projects.

Since I do not want to host all of my dependencies as a P2 repository I want all of my projects to be POM-first projects, except the eclipse-plugin one, which would be build MANIFESt-first. Is something like this possible?

I am aware that I would still need to bundle and publish my POM-first projects into a P2 repository.

With kind regards,
Jan Gräfen

Comment: The wizard doesn't do this for you, but you can configure it like that manually.

Comment: why no build the eclipse plugin pom first as well (the maven bundle plugin will help you to generate the manifest)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of pondering and some pretty frustrating try-and-errors, I realized that my approach was totally wrong.

The solution I am now running with is using the maven-dependency-plugin to copy my dependencies into a lib/ folder inside the project and then include them to the classpath in my plugin.xml.
I also use the maven-clean-plugin to delete the lib/ folder.